# May i know the element to import global transitions xml?

Tags: spring-webflow

I am using spring-webflow-2.0, I want to import globaltransitions.xml in to myflow.xml. can i use  to achieve this? Because i dont see any other element for import...please help

Thanks, 
Sundar

Answer (score 0):

You have mark your globaltransitions.xml as abstract:

`<flow abstract="true">`

and inherit this abstract flow inside your final flow definition:

`<flow parent="globaltransitions">`